# Array 2-D in java

Tags: java, loops, row, nested-loops

I want to write a java program that prints the average of each row of a two-dimensional array but it works only on the first row. I didn't know what is the problem.

This is the code:

```
    int [][] A = new int[r][c];

    for (int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the row number: "+(i+1));
        for (int j=0; j<A[i].length;j++)
            A[i][j]=kbd.nextInt();
    }

    int sum = 0, avg =0;
    for (int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<A[i].length;j++) {
            sum += A[i][j];
            avg = sum/A[i].length;
        }
        
        System.out.println("The average of the row number: "+(i+1)+" is: "+avg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that Java and JavaScript are two completely different programming languages.

Comment: You're changing `avg` inside the loop, so only the last change is relevant, which I am sure is not what you want.

Comment: You need to move your `sum` and `avg` variables inside the loop or set them back to 0 after the inner loop. Besides average should be of type double. Right now you are making integer division.

Comment: You're using integer division for your average. Also, you need to reset sum to zero before you start with a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset sum to zero every time you loop. This can be fixed by declaring the sum variable inside the for-loop instead of outside. Also avg and sum should be a double instead of a int:

```
for (int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double avg =0;
    for (int j=0; j<A[i].length;j++) {
        sum += A[i][j];
        avg = sum/A[i].length;
    }
    
    System.out.println("The average of the row number: "+(i+1)+" is: "+avg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with sum value, you don't delete value before count sum of next row. Besides I think the average can be count after loop before printing.

```
int sum = 0, avg =0;
    for (int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        for (int j=0; j<A[i].length;j++) {
            sum += A[i][j];
        }

        avg = sum/A[i].length;
        
        System.out.println("The average of the row number: "+(i+1)+" is: "+avg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double avg =0;
    for (int j=0; j<A[i].length;j++) {
        sum += A[i][j];
        avg = sum/A[i].length;
    }
    
    System.out.println("The average of the row number: "+(i+1)+" is: "+avg);
}
```

Comment: `avg = sum/A[i].length;` does not belong into the inner loop. Otherwise the average is calculated pointlessly `A[i].length - 1` times.

Answer (score 0):

*of course, You could also use a lambda and avoid such a problem in the first place*

```
for(int row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
  double avg = Arrays.stream(A[row]).boxed().collect(averagingInt(i -> i));
  System.out.println("The average of the row number: " + (row + 1) + " is: " + avg);
}
```